# Submodule and direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to prove the following resut:

Let $R=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ be $R$ regarded as $R$-module is usual way.

> Then the submodule $N=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ is not finitely generated

Hint: for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $e_n=(0,…,0,1,0,…)\in N$ (the $1$ is on the $n-$th position).

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown, there we don't use the hint

Comment: Voted to close because of this user’s persistent pattern of poor posts. This is actually the third post on the topic and it seems that they have not considered the ample hints given before.

Answer (score 2):

$N$ is the module generated by $e_i,i\in\mathbb{N}$, this implies that every $x\in N$ is of the form $x=l_{i_1}e_{i_1}+...+l_{i_m}e_{i_m}, {i_1}<i_2..<i_m$, we deduce if $m>i_m$ the $m$-coordinate of $x$ is zero.  Suppose it is finitely generated by $u_1,...,u_n$ remark that for every $i=1,...,n$, there exists $n_i$ such that for every $m>n_i$ the $m$-coordinate of $u_i$ is zero. Let $M>sup\{n_i\}$, for every $x$ in the nodule generated by $u_1,...,u_n$ and $m>M$, the $m$-coordinate of $x$ is zero. Contradiction since $e_m\in N$ and the $m$-coordinate of $e_m$ is $1$.

Comment: but where you use the hint here? here you use an inequality with the module $M$?

Comment: when you write $x=l_{i_1}e_{i_1}+...+l_{i_m}e_{i_m}, {i_1}<i_2..<i_m$, i think you mean $x=l_{i_1}e_{i_1}+...+l_{i_m}e_{i_m}+......, {i_1}<i_2..<i_m<...$ no? and what is $i_n$?

Comment: oops, its $i_m$

Comment: and how you use an inequality with the module $M$?

Comment: $M$ is not a module is the sup of a finite set of numbers.

Comment: the sup for $i$ where?

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting characterization of finitely generated modules. Call a family $\mathscr{F}$ of submodules of $M$ *directed* if, for every $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$, there exists $C\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $A+B\subseteq C$.

We can also consider $\sum\mathscr{F}$, the least submodule of $M$ containing all submodules belonging to $\mathscr{F}$.

> **Theorem.** *A module $M$ is finitely generated if and only if, for every directed family $\mathscr{F}$ of submodules of $M$, if $\sum\mathscr{F}=M$, then $M\in\mathscr{F}$.*

*Proof.* ($\implies$) Exercise. ($\impliedby$) Consider the family $\mathscr{F}$ of all finitely generated submodules of $M$. Then clearly $\mathscr{F}$ is directed and $\sum\mathscr{F}=M$. Then $M\in\mathscr{F}$ is finitely generated. □

For your problem, consider the family $\mathscr{F}=\{A_n:n\ge1\}$, where $A_n$ is the submodule of $N$ spanned by $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is clearly directed, being totally ordered by inclusion, and $\sum\mathscr{F}=N$, we conclude that $N$ is not finitely generated, because $N\notin\mathscr{F}$.

---

The condition in the theorem above can be easily dualized. A family $\mathscr{F}$ of submodule is called *filtered* if, for every $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$, there exists $C\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $C\subseteq A\cap B$.

> **Definition.** A module $M$ is *finitely cogenerated* when, for every filtered family $\mathscr{F}$ of submodules of $M$, if $\bigcap\mathscr{F}=\{0\}$, then $\{0\}\in\mathscr{F}$.

For instance, a module $M$ is artinian if and only if, for every submodule $L$ of $M$, $M/L$ is finitely cogenerated. Compare with the theorem about noetherian modules: a module $M$ is noetherian if and only if every submodule $L$ of $M$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @egereg, i think that the answer should be more simple?

Comment: @siwar Why? It *is* simple: using the condition stated in the answer the fact that $N$ is not finitely generated is immediately clear. And I gave you a good tool that you can use in the future.

Comment: thank you but i am a little bit confused since i didn't anderstand the hall answer of Tsemo Aristide, have you an idea how to write it more clear?